# Vertical align not working list menu

Tags: html, css, list, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I have list menu, but last-child menu is different style.

I try to use:

```
display: table;
vertical-align: middle;
```

but it doesn't work.

[Check my example](http://jsfiddle.net/0y9qtpvz/1/)

Please correct me.

Comment: What's wrong in the given code on jsfiddle?
It's working properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from the `.mainmenu li`, that's all causing the problem.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y9qtpvz/7/), `vertical-align` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your stylesheet

```
.mainmenu
{
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mainmenu li
{
float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/0y9qtpvz/6/
 replace following line:

```
<li><a href="#">Pay <br>Here</a></li>
```

with this:

```
<li><a href="#">Pay Here</a></li>
```

and replace following line:

```
.mainmenu{
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

with this one:

```
.mainmenu{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: actually, i want style list menu "pay here" like any brake row. different with other list :)